# A question from Halmos' Naive Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm on Section 10, *Inverses and Composites*. On page 41, Halmos considers a relation $R$ on a set $X$ and the relation of equality $I$ on $X$. He then asks the reader whether there is some connection among $I$, $R\circ R^{-1}$, and $R^{-1}\circ R$?

I can't think of any such connection. And the example (see below) I've constructed makes me believe that there isn't any. Am I correct?

---

My example:

Consider $R$ on $X=\{0, 1, 2\}$ defined by $R:=\{(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2)\}$.
Then $I=\{(0, 0), (1,1), (2,2)\}$, $R\circ R^{-1} = \{(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2,1)\}$, and $R^{-1}\circ R=\{(0,0), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1)\}$.

I don't see any obvious connection among $I$, $R\circ R^{-1}$, and $R^{-1}\circ R$.

---

For a relation $R$, Halmos defines the relation $R^{-1}$ as $\forall x, y(yR^{-1}x\iff xRy)$.

For relations $R\subset X\times Y$ and $S\subset Y\times Z$, Halmos defines $S\circ R$ as $\forall x,z\Big((x,z)\in S\circ R\iff x\in X\wedge z\in Z\wedge\exists y\in Y\big((x, y)\in R\wedge (y, z)\in S)\big)\Big)$.

Comment: I think you're missing $(2,1)$ from $R\circ R^{-1}$. I can't comment because I don't know the context of Halmos' question.

Comment: There is an obvious relation when the domain or range of $R$ is all of $X$. There is something sort of analogous in the general case, but that's a little bit of a stretch to call a connection.

Comment: A little more generally, if $\operatorname{dom}R\cup\operatorname{ran}R=X$, there’s an easy relationship between $(R\circ R^{-1})\cup(R^{-1}\circ R)$ and $I$.

Comment: @Chrystomath Thanks for pointing it out, editing!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yea, I thought that too (it’ll be just the connection of $I$ being a subset of their union, right?), but I wondered if it was what really Halmos was expecting.

Comment: @Atom: Yes, that’s right. I don’t see anything else at the moment.

Comment: Maybe something like this: the range of $R$ is all of $X$ precisely when $I \subseteq R \circ R^{-1}$. And similarly for $R^{-1} \circ R$ and the domain of $R$.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Thanks! That seems to be “the correct answer.”

Comment: @Atom I'll post it as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of $R$ is all of $X$ precisely when $I \subseteq R \circ R^{-1}$. Similarly, we have that the domain of $R$ is all of $X$ precisely when $I \subseteq R^{-1} \circ R$.

To prove this it suffices the prove the first statement. Then the second statement follows by swapping the roles of $R$ and $R^{-1}$. The proof is an easy exercise, but let's include it for completeness' sake.

So suppose that the range of $R$ is all of $X$. Let $x \in X$ and let $(y, x) \in R$ for some $y$. Then $(x, y) \in R^{-1}$ and so $(x, x) \in R \circ R^{-1}$. Since $x$ was arbitrary we have $I \subseteq R \circ R^{-1}$. For the converse we suppose that $I \subseteq R \circ R^{-1}$ and we let $x \in X$. Then since $(x, x) \in I \subseteq R \circ R^{-1}$ there must be some $y \in X$ such that $(y, x) \in R$ and $(x, y) \in R^{-1}$. So $x$ is indeed in the range of $R$.